# How to remove rows in vector that do not appear in another one?

Tags: vector, rows

I have two numeric vectors with different lengths! Lets say `a` has a length of 7000 and `b` 6000. All the rownames in `b` are present in `a`. I have to remove those extra rows in `a` that cannot be matched to `b`.
Any body can help me doing that?

Comment: Oh sorry guys, I was looking for R forums that I ended up here so I didn't mention where am I doing this. It is in R! And I am not an IT person, just trying to learn R for my work which is biology!

Answer (score 0):

Simples solution would be to iterate through a and b and check for duplicates, like this:

```
for i in a
    for j in b
        if j == i
            delete i
            break
        end
    end
end
```

It's in pseudocode, as you did not mention any specific language

Answer (score 0):

It's really depend on the language and how you implement "vectors"

I can give you a general example like

```
for(int i = b.length ; i < a.length ; i++)
{
   delete(a[i]);
}
```

But it's of no use in any language because I need a lot more information from you plus what you tried.

Comment: Please see my comment on the question.

Comment: @Parham sorry, can't help you there. you should post a new question and be a lot more specific